# Golang Construct Months for options in html select tag

Tags: go

I have just started learning Golang and would like to list months in order for a options in an html select tag:

I have started this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

var months = [12]string{
    "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December",
}

func main(){
    for i, n := range months {
        fmt.Printf("%2d: %s\n", i, n)
    }
}
```

I would like to print out this:

```
<option>January</option>
<option>February</option>
<option>March</option>
<option>April</option>
<option>May</option>
<option>June</option>
<option>July</option>
<option>August</option>
<option>September</option>
<option>October</option>
<option>November</option>
<option>December</option>
```

Comment: If you're actually putting this into a HTML template, then the existing answers (and your approach) won't help at all. You'll just want to `{{ range }}` over a slice provided to your template. Take a look at http://jan.newmarch.name/golang/template/chapter-template.html for examples.

Comment: @elithrar  Can you provide an example of how to insert this into an html template?  The examples are like greek to me as a noob.

Comment: Take a look at the example here: http://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/ - which shows how to pass things to `ExecuteTemplate`. If you get stuck I recommend asking on the [go-nuts mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/golang-nuts) or #go-nuts on Freenode (IRC).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    for i := time.January; i <= time.December; i++ {
        fmt.Printf("<option>%s</option>\n", i)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
<option>January</option>
<option>February</option>
<option>March</option>
<option>April</option>
<option>May</option>
<option>June</option>
<option>July</option>
<option>August</option>
<option>September</option>
<option>October</option>
<option>November</option>
<option>December</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are nearly there:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

var months = [12]string{
    "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December",
}

func main() {
    for _, month := range months {
        fmt.Printf("<option>%s</option>\n", month)
    }
}
```

The only tricky part is to use `_` instead of `i`, to avoid an error "*i declared and not used*" when you try to build your program.
`_` is called the *blank identifier*, you can learn more [in the go documentation](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#blank).